# LNK2019 error from SDL tutorial, but only in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I'm doing LazyFoo's SDLTutorial setup for VS2010 and I'm having trouble getting it to cooperate. What's strange is that I can get it to work seemingly fine on VS2008.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;    
}
```

This is the error messages that it gives me

```
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I've followed the steps, step by step, at least 4 times at this point and I continue to get these errors. I'm considering going back to 2008 if I can't get this resolved, but I'd rather stay with 2010. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check the project settings side-by-side. I'm positive the difference is in there somewhere. I'd start with the linker configuration.

Answer (score 3):

That means the linker cannot find the libraries. Double check the settings in

`Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker`

1. Specify the directory: **General**, **Additional Library Directories**: `<path>\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86`

   and
2. Specify the files: **Input**, **Additional Dependencies**: `SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib;`

Comment: Well that got rid of the first two messages, but now it still gives me the last one. Changing the first post to reflect this, as the last error message is the one that has been the same on all the remakes.

Answer (score 1):

If you did that already and you are still getting the same error. It might be that you didnt write your main so that it allows command arguments. It should look like this.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){ // your code here }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fail to include optional command line arguments in your main(), you will get errors when trying to compile anything that contains SDL2, so the proper solution is to always remember doing what [Rafael said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406392).

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){}
```

This resolves all the issues if you are sure you included the libraries properly.